# Adding mapping to collections.mutable.Map fails when map is empty

Tags: scala, dictionary

I'm making a new mutable map like this:

```
var optionMap = mutable.Map[String, Map[String, Array[String]]]()
```

Later, I try to add something to it with the following:

```
optionMap(definitelyAString) += (alsoAString -> definitelyAnArray)
```

This always fails with a `NoSuchElementException`. I know there shouldn't be an entry for `definitelyAString` because I just made it. I would expect that Scala would then make an entry for that key and drop the new mapping of `(alsoAString -> definitelyAnArray)` into it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the `Map` before you can index it.

```
optionMap += ("definitelyAString" -> Map("alsoAString" -> definitelyAnArray))
```

The syntax you used will modify an existing entry.

```
optionMap("definitelyAString") += ("otherString" -> otherArray)
```

Now the `Map` located at `optionMap("definitelyAString")` contains 2 key->value entries, one for the key `"alsoAString"` and one for the key `"otherString"`.